# LDAP root query syntax to search more than one specific OU

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ou

I need to run a single LDAP query that will search through two specific organization units (OU) in the root query however I'm having a tough go of it. I've tried the following queries below and neither were successful:

```
(|(OU=Staff,DC=my,DC=super,DC=org)(OU=Vendors,DC=my,DC=super,DC=org))

((OU=Staff,DC=my,DC=super,DC=org) | (OU=Vendors,DC=my,DC=super,DC=org))
```

My question is; is it possible to query more than one single OU **in a single query?** Assuming that it is what the proper syntax for this type of expression in the root LDAP query.

Comment: If the `ou` attribute is allowed by the objectClasses which comprise the entries for which the LDAP client searches, the `ou` attribute could be used in a search filter. Of course, this requires adding the `ou` attribute to the entries in question. This might be an effective solution since AD does not support the excellent suggestion below of extensible match filters.

Comment: It would be nice if you could mark my answer as the accepted one since the currently accepted seems obviously not entirely valid (anymore?) and wrong regarding AD and thus in general. It may be valid only for some LDAP implementations.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can!!! In short use this as the connection string:

```
ldap://<host>:3268/DC=<my>,DC=<domain>?cn
```

together with your search filter, e.g.

```
(&(sAMAccountName={0})(&((objectCategory=person)(objectclass=user)(mail=*)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=<some-special-nested-group>,OU=<ou3>,OU=<ou2>,OU=<ou1>,DC=<dc3>,DC=<dc2>,DC=<dc1>))))
```

That will search in the so called [Global Catalog](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978012.aspx), that had been available out-of-the-box in our environment.

Instead of the known/common other versions (or combinations thereof) that **did NOT work in our environment** with multiple OUs:

```
ldap://<host>/DC=<my>,DC=<domain>
ldap://<host>:389/DC=<my>,DC=<domain>  (standard port)
ldap://<host>/OU=<someOU>,DC=<my>,DC=<domain>
ldap://<host>/CN=<someCN>,DC=<my>,DC=<domain>
ldap://<host>/(|(OU=<someOU1>)(OU=<someOU2>)),DC=<my>,DC=<domain> (search filters here shouldn't work at all by definition)
```

(I am a developer, not an AD/LDAP guru:) Damn I had been searching for this solution everywhere for almost 2 days and almost gave up, getting used to the thought I might have to implement this obviously very common scenario by hand (with Jasperserver/Spring security(/Tomcat)).
(So this shall be a reminder if somebody else or me should have this problem again in the future :O) )

Here some other related threads I found during my research that had been mostly of little help:

- [the **solution** hidden in a comment of LarreDo from 2006](http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Support/AuthenticationWithApacheAndLDAP)
- [some Microsoft answered question of **best practices** how to **design** your organization in the **directory**, stating using multiple top-level OUs in bigger companies is not unusual or even suitable](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/064aa5c9-f040-45b6-b36a-38d1823c16a1/active-directory-design-multiple-domains-or-organizational-units)
- [Tim Wong (2011) added that this **may be a problem of unresolvable DNS names** in the **ForestDNSZones** (part of the AD top-level domain used)](http://answers.atlassian.com/questions/2786/handling-multiple-ldap-ous-in-jira-4-3)
- [**example code** for implementing it by hand when using **Spring security** (e.g. also used in Jasper)](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/47858-ldap-query-multiple-ou-s)
- [John Morrissey (2012) suggested it **could be related to some security settings** and it may work if you use TLS (I guess if the LDAP server wants to restrict such global searches for non-secure connections - which would not seem a good (its kind of half-baked) security approach to me)](http://forums.proftpd.org/smf/index.php/topic,7096.msg18382.html?PHPSESSID=at7pgqrooq1p8hab44q34969f7#msg18382)
- [awatkins (2012) used **some hacking approach** in some **mod_ldap.c** code (of whatever software)](http://forums.proftpd.org/smf/index.php/topic,7096.msg29856.html?PHPSESSID=at7pgqrooq1p8hab44q34969f7#msg29856)

And here I will provide our anonymized Tomcat LDAP config in case it may be helpful
(`/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF/applicationContext-externalAUTH-LDAP.xml`):

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

<!-- ############ LDAP authentication ############ - Sample configuration 
    of external authentication via an external LDAP server. -->


<bean id="proxyAuthenticationProcessingFilter"
    class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.BaseAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager">
        <ref local="ldapAuthenticationManager" />
    </property>
    <property name="externalDataSynchronizer">
        <ref local="externalDataSynchronizer" />
    </property>

    <property name="sessionRegistry">
        <ref bean="sessionRegistry" />
    </property>

    <property name="internalAuthenticationFailureUrl" value="/login.html?error=1" />
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/loginsuccess.html" />
    <property name="invalidateSessionOnSuccessfulAuthentication"
        value="true" />
    <property name="migrateInvalidatedSessionAttributes" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="proxyAuthenticationSoapProcessingFilter"
    class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.DefaultAuthenticationSoapProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="ldapAuthenticationManager" />
    <property name="externalDataSynchronizer" ref="externalDataSynchronizer" />

    <property name="invalidateSessionOnSuccessfulAuthentication"
        value="true" />
    <property name="migrateInvalidatedSessionAttributes" value="true" />
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/services" />
</bean>

<bean id="proxyRequestParameterAuthenticationFilter"
    class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.ExternalRequestParameterAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager">
        <ref local="ldapAuthenticationManager" />
    </property>
    <property name="externalDataSynchronizer" ref="externalDataSynchronizer" />

    <property name="authenticationFailureUrl">
        <value>/login.html?error=1</value>
    </property>
    <property name="excludeUrls">
        <list>
            <value>/j_spring_switch_user</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="proxyBasicProcessingFilter"
    class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.ExternalAuthBasicProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="ldapAuthenticationManager" />
    <property name="externalDataSynchronizer" ref="externalDataSynchronizer" />

    <property name="authenticationEntryPoint">
        <ref local="basicProcessingFilterEntryPoint" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="proxyAuthenticationRestProcessingFilter"
    class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.DefaultAuthenticationRestProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager">
        <ref local="ldapAuthenticationManager" />
    </property>
    <property name="externalDataSynchronizer">
        <ref local="externalDataSynchronizer" />
    </property>

    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/rest/login" />
    <property name="invalidateSessionOnSuccessfulAuthentication"
        value="true" />
    <property name="migrateInvalidatedSessionAttributes" value="true" />
</bean>



<bean id="ldapAuthenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.providers.ProviderManager">
    <property name="providers">
        <list>
            <ref local="ldapAuthenticationProvider" />
            <ref bean="${bean.daoAuthenticationProvider}" />
            <!--anonymousAuthenticationProvider only needed if filterInvocationInterceptor.alwaysReauthenticate 
                is set to true <ref bean="anonymousAuthenticationProvider"/> -->
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="ldapAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.providers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.security.providers.ldap.authenticator.BindAuthenticator">
            <constructor-arg>
                <ref local="ldapContextSource" />
            </constructor-arg>
            <property name="userSearch" ref="userSearch" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.security.ldap.populator.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
            <constructor-arg index="0">
                <ref local="ldapContextSource" />
            </constructor-arg>
            <constructor-arg index="1">
                <value></value>
            </constructor-arg>

            <property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="cn" />
            <property name="convertToUpperCase" value="true" />
            <property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_" />
            <property name="groupSearchFilter"
                value="(&amp;(member={0})(&amp;(objectCategory=Group)(objectclass=group)(cn=my-nested-group-name)))" />
            <property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
            <!-- Can setup additional external default roles here <property name="defaultRole" 
                value="LDAP"/> -->
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="userSearch"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <value></value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <value>(&amp;(sAMAccountName={0})(&amp;((objectCategory=person)(objectclass=user)(mail=*)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=my-nested-group-name,OU=ou3,OU=ou2,OU=ou1,DC=dc3,DC=dc2,DC=dc1))))
        </value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="2">
        <ref local="ldapContextSource" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="searchSubtree">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="ldapContextSource"
    class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.ldap.JSLdapContextSource">
    <constructor-arg value="ldap://myhost:3268/DC=dc3,DC=dc2,DC=dc1?cn" />
    <!-- manager user name and password (may not be needed) -->
    <property name="userDn" value="CN=someuser,OU=ou4,OU=1,DC=dc3,DC=dc2,DC=dc1" />
    <property name="password" value="somepass" />
    <!--End Changes -->
</bean>
<!-- ############ LDAP authentication ############ -->

<!-- ############ JRS Synchronizer ############ -->
<bean id="externalDataSynchronizer"
    class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.ExternalDataSynchronizerImpl">
    <property name="externalUserProcessors">
        <list>
            <ref local="externalUserSetupProcessor" />
            <!-- Example processor for creating user folder -->
            <!--<ref local="externalUserFolderProcessor"/> -->
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="abstractExternalProcessor"
    class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.processors.AbstractExternalUserProcessor"
    abstract="true">
    <property name="repositoryService" ref="${bean.repositoryService}" />
    <property name="userAuthorityService" ref="${bean.userAuthorityService}" />
    <property name="tenantService" ref="${bean.tenantService}" />
    <property name="profileAttributeService" ref="profileAttributeService" />
    <property name="objectPermissionService" ref="objectPermissionService" />
</bean>

<bean id="externalUserSetupProcessor"
    class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.processors.ExternalUserSetupProcessor"
    parent="abstractExternalProcessor">
    <property name="userAuthorityService">
        <ref bean="${bean.internalUserAuthorityService}" />
    </property>
    <property name="defaultInternalRoles">
        <list>
            <value>ROLE_USER</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="organizationRoleMap">
        <map>
            <!-- Example of mapping customer roles to JRS roles -->
            <entry>
                <key>
                    <value>ROLE_MY-NESTED-GROUP-NAME</value>
                </key>
                <!-- JRS role that the <key> external role is mapped to -->
                <value>ROLE_USER</value>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<!--bean id="externalUserFolderProcessor" class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.processors.ExternalUserFolderProcessor" 
    parent="abstractExternalProcessor"> <property name="repositoryService" ref="${bean.unsecureRepositoryService}"/> 
    </bean -->

<!-- ############ JRS Synchronizer ############ -->
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem but I'm using different code. Could you please read my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971315/finding-active-directory-users-from-2-ou

Answer (score 17):

The answer is NO you can't. Why?

Because the LDAP standard describes a LDAP-SEARCH as kind of function with 4 parameters:

1. The node where the search should begin, which is a Distinguish Name (DN)
2. The attributes you want to be brought back
3. The depth of the search (base, one-level, subtree)
4. The filter

You are interested in the filter. You've got a summary [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (it's provided by Microsoft for Active Directory, it's from a standard). The filter is composed, in a boolean way, by expression of the type `Attribute Operator Value`.

So the filter you give does not mean anything.

On the theoretical point of view there is [ExtensibleMatch](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/ExtensibleMatch) that allows buildind filters on the DN path, but it's not supported by Active Directory.

As far as I know, you have to use an attribute in AD to make the distinction for users in the two OUs.

It can be any existing discriminator attribute, or, for example the attribute called OU which is inherited from `organizationalPerson` class. you can set it (it's not automatic, and will not be maintained if you move the users) with "staff" for some users and "vendors" for others and them use the filter:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(|(ou=staff)(ou=vendors)))
```

Comment: Can we filter using the distinguishedName attribute like (distinguishedName=*OUPath) ?

Comment: Whats the best way to populate the OU attribute? I was going to write a PS script that runs daily and looks at the OU a user is in and then writes the unique OU value to the OU attribute. I assume OU is just a name and changing it will not affect any thing else?

Comment: @DevilWAH, If you have a look to the schema, it's a directory string, and it 's facultative for organizationalPerson or user.

Comment: OK brilliant, I was really checking that it was not possible to "throw" a switch that would populate from DN. As it is I will add it to daily matanince script

Answer (score 7):

It's simple. Just change the port. Use 3268 instead of 389. If your domain name *DOMAIN.LOCAL*, in search put *DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL*

**Port 3268:** This port is used for queries that are specifically targeted for the global catalog.  LDAP requests sent to port 3268 can be used to search objects in the entire forest.  However, only the attributes marked for replication to the global catalog can be returned.

**Port 389:** This port is used for requesting information from the Domain Controller.  LDAP requests sent to port 389 can be used to search objects only within the global catalog’s home domain.  However, the application can possible to obtain all of the attributes searched objects.

Comment: Does this port work with ldaps or is there another one for that?

Comment: 3268 is GC plain text. 3269 is GC over SSL which is encrypted by default.
 
389 is AD plain text. 636 is AD over SSL which is encrypted by default.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible with AD. The distinguishedName attribute is the only thing I know of that contains the OU piece on which you're trying to search, so you'd need a wildcard to get results for objects under those OUs. Unfortunately, the wildcard character [isn't supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684431%28VS.85%29.aspx) on DNs.

If at all possible, I'd really look at doing this in 2 queries using OU=Staff... and OU=Vendors... as the base DNs.

Comment: Unfortunately this is being used by SharePoint as the root query to resolve members and I cannot change SharePoint.

Comment: We had a similar situation. We were able to solve it through a combo of other attributes: mail, useraccountcontrol, etc. that identified just the users we wanted.

Comment: In the case of SharePoint, why not just add another import connection with the OUs as search bases? Here's how to for multiple forests: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263247(office.12).aspx

Comment: Isn't this just for Profile import? My need has more to do with name resolution in SharePoint (E.G. People Picker control)

Comment: That's correct - I didn't realize you were looking to limit the people picker. I'd edit your original question to note that it's what you're looking to filter or you're liable to see another "can't be done" answer. In the case of the people picker, it does look possible using the Peoplepicker-serviceaccountdirectorypaths stsadm property: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263012(office.12).aspx . You just need to supply a semicolon separated list of OUs as a propertyvalue. So, "OU=Staff,DC=my,DC=super,DC=org;OU=Vendors,DC=my,DC=super,DC=org" in your case.

Answer (score 2):

After speaking with an LDAP expert, it's not possible this way. One query can't search more than one DC or OU.

Your options are:

> 1. Run more then 1 query and parse the result.
> 2. Use a filter to find the desired users/objects based off a different attribute like an AD group or by name.

Answer (score 2):

### tl;dr -- Use `ou:dn:=<val>` syntax

For the OP's question, the way to do it would be:

```
ldapsearch -b "DC=my,DC=super,DC=org" <other_options> "(|(ou:dc:=Staff)(ou:dc:=Vendors))"
```

---

In principle, your case is tricky because the OU values do not appear in a user's `ldapsearch` output -- OU values are part of the DN.

For example, the search result here:

```
[root@pg data]# ldapsearch -H "ldap://ldap-service" -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org" -w admin -b"DC=example,DC=org" cn=testuser2 
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <DC=example,DC=org> with scope subtree
# filter: cn=testuser2
# requesting: ALL
#

# testuser2, AU, IIQ, example.org
dn: cn=testuser2,ou=AU,ou=IIQ,dc=example,dc=org
cn: testuser2
displayName: pgtest
gidNumber: 500
givenName: testuser2
homeDirectory: /home/testuser2
loginShell: /bin/sh
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
userPassword:: e01ENX1GMnFxVVpDTjh4VVJveGg5bkJBcGF3PT0=
sn: testuser2
uidNumber: 1012
uid: testuser2

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

There is no `ou:` line because the OU belongs to the `dn:` line.  So if you tack on an `ou` to the search, you'll see that it is `requesting: ou` instead of `requesting: ALL`, but no attributes get listed:

```
[root@pg data]# ldapsearch -H "ldap://ldap-service" -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org" -w admin -b"DC=example,DC=org" cn=testuser2 ou
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <DC=example,DC=org> with scope subtree
# filter: cn=testuser2
# requesting: ou 
#

# testuser2, AU, IIQ, example.org
dn: cn=testuser2,ou=AU,ou=IIQ,dc=example,dc=org

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

Searching on OU will give you results, but they are only the OU objects, not the users themselves:

```
[root@pg data]# ldapsearch -H "ldap://ldap-service" -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org" -w admin -b"DC=example,DC=org" "(|(OU=IN)(OU=AU))"
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <DC=example,DC=org> with scope subtree
# filter: (|(OU=IN)(OU=AU))
# requesting: ALL
#

# IN, example.org
dn: ou=IN,dc=example,dc=org
ou: IN
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top

# AU, example.org
dn: ou=AU,dc=example,dc=org
ou: AU
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top

# IN, IIQ, example.org
dn: ou=IN,ou=IIQ,dc=example,dc=org
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: IN

# AU, IIQ, example.org
dn: ou=AU,ou=IIQ,dc=example,dc=org
ou: AU
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 5
# numEntries: 4
```

However, `ldapsearch` allows you to extract parts of the DN with `ou:dn:=<val>` syntax:

```
[root@pg data]# ldapsearch -H "ldap://ldap-service" -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org" -w admin -b"DC=example,DC=org" "(&(displayname=pgtest)(|(ou:dn:=IN)(ou:dn:=AU)))" cn displayname
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <DC=example,DC=org> with scope subtree
# filter: (&(displayname=pgtest)(|(ou:dn:=IN)(ou:dn:=AU)))
# requesting: cn displayname 
#

# testuser3, AU, example.org
dn: cn=testuser3,ou=AU,dc=example,dc=org
cn: testuser3
displayName: pgtest

# testuser4, IN, example.org
dn: cn=testuser4,ou=IN,dc=example,dc=org
cn: testuser4
displayName: pgtest

# testuser2, AU, IIQ, example.org
dn: cn=testuser2,ou=AU,ou=IIQ,dc=example,dc=org
cn: testuser2
displayName: pgtest

# testuser1, IN, IIQ, example.org
dn: cn=testuser1,ou=IN,ou=IIQ,dc=example,dc=org
cn: testuser1
displayName: pgtest

# testuser14, IN, example.org
dn: cn=testuser14,ou=IN,dc=example,dc=org
cn: testuser14
displayName: pgtest

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 6
# numEntries: 5
```