# How to include multiple OU from AD account in a single search using PrincipleSearcher in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, directoryservices, principalcontext, principalsearcher

**Scenario:** `Active Directory` username search should return results against a search item (i.e. Firstname or Surname). There are 6 countries that are setup as different organizational units for AD accounts. e.g. UK (OU= UK), France (OU = FR). Now user should be displayed with a username which may belong to either OU=UK or OU=FR.

I am using `PrincipalSearcher` from `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` library

```
 PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "myDomain",
                                                    "OU=UK,dc=comp,dc=com");
```

**Problem:** The above allows to return usernames which only belongs to OU=UK.

**Question:** How can I add multiple Organizational Units in `PrincipalContext`.

Answer (score 0):

Try change the base object to OU=UK,OU=FR,DC=dc,DC=sys.... it might work,

Please look at the following link for details

http://ldapmaven.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/

**EDIT :**

It seems like it is not possible, please look at the following SO link,

[LDAP root query syntax to search more than one specific OU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184978/ldap-root-query-syntax-to-search-more-than-one-specific-ou)

Comment: I am afraid this hasn't worked when I tried before and gave following error: System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalOperationException was unhandled by user code
  InnerException: System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException
       Message=There is no such object on the server.

Comment: Actually taking off the OU completely searched against entire AD. That worked for searching usernames against all users in AD.