# php search multiple OUs

Tags: php, ldap

Our users in Active Directory are in various 'root' Organizational Units, how can I search for them?

What I currently have working is:

```
$search = "CN=John Doe"
$user = "username"
$psw = "password"
$server = "ldap://servername.eng.company.co.uk";
$dn = "OU=North,DC=eng,DC=company,DC=co,DC=uk"; //this is where we have others, like OU=South,DC=eng,DC=company,DC=co,DC=uk but I need the users to search them all as they don't know what OU they are in
$ds=ldap_connect($server);
$r=ldap_bind($ds, $user , $psw); 
$sr=ldap_search($ds, $dn, $search);
$data = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);
```

if I remove the OU part completely then it brings nothing back.

I have tried making it an array and doing the `ldap_search` in a foreach loop but that brings nothing back either.

Please can someone point me in the right direction? many thanks

Comment: Organisational Unit (I think)

Comment: Is the example [in the php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php) no use to you?

Comment: that's not searching multiple OUs (as far as I can see)

Comment: Read this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184978/ldap-root-query-syntax-to-search-more-than-one-specific-ou

Answer (score 0):

As ldap_search by default does a subtree-search you should be able to use

$dn = "dc=company,dc=co,dc=uk";