# LDAP Searching two groups

Tags: java, ldap

i am trying a ldap search by java. I am using ldap ctx.

I found that there are two small trees i need to search from.
For example:

```
resultsTest = lctx.search("OU=Company Beta,DC=example,DC=com", "something", SUBTREE_SCOPE);
```

(I am sure that "something" is correct because i tested a lot for the result)

There are team A, team B, team C, and team D inside Company Beta.

I found that if i add any one of them to the beginning of the search,

```
OU=team A
```

or

```
OU=team B
```

I can search the member in team A or team B.
But i want to result search from team A and team B instead of search either one of them.

Can any one provide a helping hand? I had search from a lot of website but cannot found the solution.

Comment: Unfortunately [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184978/ldap-root-query-syntax-to-search-more-than-one-specific-ou) says no, you can't. Unfortunately there's no syntax that would allow you to specify a different search base like that. However, if all the users were in groups for `team A` and `team B` then you could filter with the `memberOf` attribute with a logical or condition (this is presuming active directory which has `memberOf` attributes for group memberships for user accounts)

Answer (score 1):

many LDAP Server implementations will allow an [extensible match search filter](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/ExtensibleMatch) as defined in RFC 2254 that may allow you to perform just that.

Define your base above the OUs you wish to include within the search and then use a filter something like:

```
(&(|(ou:dn:=TeamA)(ou:dn:=TeamB))(objectclass=inetorgperson)(sn=willeke))
```

Let us know hot it goes.

Comment: I tried add (|(ou:dn:=TeamA)(ou:dn:=TeamB)) to the search filter, it didn't work.(Which means 0 result in return).

Comment: Which Ldap server are you using?