# Query LDAP - MS Active Directory - Guacamole

Tags: windows, active-directory, ldap, guacamole

i am installing a sofware called Guacamole :

http://guacamole.incubator.apache.org/

i have installed with success , but i am facing some problems when i am trying integrate with active directory ( Windows Server 2003 R2 )

here is my ldap query that work it.

```
ldap-user-base-dn: OU:Group IT,DC=kamikaze,DC=com,DC=br
```

With this , the users that are at OU : Group IT can connect at Guacamole , but i have Two OU , how could i insert the two OU at my Query ?

Comment: Have a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/19044146 for composing multiple OU in the ldap query.

Comment: unhappy dont work , i dont know if this its because guacamole limitation

Comment: `guacamole limitation` it's better check with their dev support, so clarify your doubt.

Comment: i made a post at Nabble forum , but i dont know if they can see my post. u could see ? http://apache-guacamole-incubating-users.2363388.n4.nabble.com/Guacamole-Multiples-OU-s-at-same-active-Directory-td1111.html